# I don't know how to solve $\frac{y}{y+x}=y'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We got

$$\frac{dx}{x+y}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{u+y^3e^y}$$

But as said I need to calculate

$$\frac{y}{y+x}=y'$$

But I don't know how to do that

Any ideas?

Comment: Try substitution: $y(x) = xv(x)$

Comment: How does $u$ fit into this?

Comment: @J.G. This looks like an intermediate step in solving a first order PDE using method of characteristics. The $u$ is not really relevant to the question, just a part of the setup that led to it.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x/y=v$ and then you will get a differential in only x and v which can be easily separated out and integrated.

Some more hint :
$x=vy$. What is $dy/dx$ in terms of x and v? The L.H.S becomes $\frac{1}{(1+v)}$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y}{x+y}\\
\implies &\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{x}{y}+1\\
\implies &\dfrac{y\times dx-x\times dy}{y^2}=\dfrac{dy}{y}\\
\implies &d\left(\dfrac xy\right)=d(\log y)\\
\implies &\boxed{\dfrac xy=\log y+C}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dx}{x+y}=\frac{dy}{y}$$
$$y{dx}=({x+y})dy$$
$$ydx-xdy=ydy$$
$$\dfrac {ydx-xdy}{y^2}=\dfrac {dy}{y}$$
$$d \left (\dfrac {x}{y} \right)=\dfrac {dy}{y}$$
Integrate.
You can also consider $x'$ instead of $y'$
$$x'=\frac x y+1$$
This a first order linear DE. That's easy to solve.

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and mine (which was posted $17$ minutes before yours)?

Comment: I didnt read your answer. @Martund I wanted to solve it wih exactness. And thats different.

Comment: No I m not going to delete it since I choose the method of exactness from the start and thats not what you did. End of this . @Martund